# Why is my Heroku deployment not recognising my Procfile?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app using Heroku.

I tried via CLI and also graphically in their user portal.

I get this problem in the build log:

```
 Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

It's not reading my Procfile.

Here's some of the latest lines of my error logs:

```
2020-05-08T04:32:57.546072+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 02e1e06c by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T04:32:57.546072+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T04:33:05.475821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=ff88cf27-54c2
-4611-b611-ce36c41b09f6 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T04:33:06.086210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=a4
690f93-c8e3-4256-b46b-a8d1e69109c1 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T04:33:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-08T10:04:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:04.414084+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:04.414084+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 92e0c7b1 by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:37.245718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=9cb80bd2-7cb6
-4e20-ad8a-e61aeeab0e02 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T10:05:39.210072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=a2
9bf337-c13a-4eb7-83ef-e221bc69b6b7 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T10:05:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

It's not a text file.

Here is my edited directory. Steps I've done to resolve:

1. Refactored the name
2. Ran it locally
3. git push heroku master

I've also deleted the other copy of the Procfile as i thought it may be causing conflicts. I do think it has something to do with my directories. I did get quite confused with the directories in the tutorial because i stupidly personally named them :(

[image: Here is my screenshot as requested of my chnages]

Also here is my updated logs:

```
2020-05-10T12:45:29.755415+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=e0
4a8cbd-ea93-408d-bc4a-02c712aac84d fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-11T00:40:58.769115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=dd461869-8299
-4eab-888c-c5ad06b13a22 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-11T00:40:59.344106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=1c
21d6da-9b1b-4246-acc6-11e4648ec474 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

EDIT 2:

As suggested in another post I tried the following

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 -a Danslist_Project
```

Then I thought I'd try other names too as I think i'm confused with the names and directories.

[image: Different Names Tried]

EDIT 3:
Ok, so I took a look at that site and noticed I had two apps here. Note that I have now tried them both. See below screenshots:

[image: my two apps]

[[image: Error Description[3]]

EDIT 4:

Forgot to add the -a switch on Danslist but still got an error. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your project name is causing errors, Try to rename it so it not includes a space.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried changing the name > comit > push to Heroku master and still joy I’m afraid.

Comment: changing the dir name of Project does not changes project name you also have to make other edits too, search about this on Google and then run in your local host if it runs there then you are ready to go after changing `Procfile` content to satisfy your new project name.

Comment: I can run it locally so that's fine. It's not still not picking up the file

Comment: can you update your `Procfile` here so it matches latest version i.e with latest project name.

Comment: Hi i updated the original post

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: I've added a answer, hope that helps. By the way for this you should've created new post and not delete previous questions and content.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory name contains a space in Profile which is causing errors change your project name.

Update # 2:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. To fix it, scale your web dynos to 1 or more dynos:

`heroku ps:scale web=1`, if this asks for an app try running this.

`heroku ps:scale web=1 -a your_heroku_appname`

Comment: Hey, that's also the next step of my tutorial actually. I'll update the original post. I really do think it's something to do with the names. I've screwed up something there i think.

Comment: Here you have to give app_name which you set in Heroku not Django's project name, seen here https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps. I think in your case it is herokudanslist, i may be incorrect.

Comment: Hey, damn, i tried them both :( see latest edit in op. This is it here. https://github.com/weazzyefff/Danslist

Comment: What else should i do? Thank you for all the help. I appreciate it. The -a did nothing.

Comment: Update your question with `-a` included and delete unnecessary details. That is why you should've created another question at first place

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't exactly know what the unecessary details are?? I updated my OP with the ```-a``` included

Comment: Please run this `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a danslist` or `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a herokudanslist` with a small `d` or `h` respectively.