# Why am i getting errors trying to deploy my app to Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app using Heroku.

I tried via CLI and also graphically in their user portal.

I get this problem in the build log:

```
 Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

It's not reading my Procfile.

Here's some of the latest lines of my error logs:

```
2020-05-08T04:32:57.546072+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 02e1e06c by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T04:32:57.546072+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T04:33:05.475821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=ff88cf27-54c2
-4611-b611-ce36c41b09f6 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T04:33:06.086210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=a4
690f93-c8e3-4256-b46b-a8d1e69109c1 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T04:33:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-08T10:04:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:04.414084+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:04.414084+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 92e0c7b1 by user djrgrey@gmail.com
2020-05-08T10:05:37.245718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=9cb80bd2-7cb6
-4e20-ad8a-e61aeeab0e02 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T10:05:39.210072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=a2
9bf337-c13a-4eb7-83ef-e221bc69b6b7 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T10:05:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

It's not a text file.

Here is my edited directory. Steps I've done to resolve:

1. Refactored the name
2. Ran it locally
3. git push heroku master

I've also deleted the other copy of the Procfile as i thought it may be causing conflicts. I do think it has something to do with my directories. I did get quite confused with the directories in the tutorial because i stupidly personally named them :(

[image: Here is my screenshot as requested of my chnages]

Also here is my updated logs:

```
2020-05-10T12:45:29.755415+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=e0
4a8cbd-ea93-408d-bc4a-02c712aac84d fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-11T00:40:58.769115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=dd461869-8299
-4eab-888c-c5ad06b13a22 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-11T00:40:59.344106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=herokudanslist.herokuapp.com request_id=1c
21d6da-9b1b-4246-acc6-11e4648ec474 fwd="118.149.66.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

EDIT 2:

As suggested in another post I tried the following

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 -a Danslist_Project
```

Then I thought I'd try other names too as I think i'm confused with the names and directories.

[image: Different Names Tried]

EDIT 3:
Ok, so I took a look at that site and noticed I had two apps here. Note that I have now tried them both. See below screenshots:

[image: my two apps]

[[image: Error Description[3]]

EDIT 4:

Forgot to add the -a switch on Danslist but still got an error. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Heroku deployment not recognising my Procfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689534/why-is-my-heroku-deployment-not-recognising-my-procfile)

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of another question you asked. [Please don't repeat questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339627/354577).